# Rails unit testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-3

In one of my Rails test case:

```
test "something" do
  assert_raise RuntimeError do
    @foo.bar
  end
end
```

I set up the `@foo` object such that `@foo.bar` does ***not*** raise `RuntimeError` (ie, the test case will fail)

But the following code passed the test:

```
test "something" do
  blah(@foo)
end

private
  def blah(foo)
    assert RuntimeError do
      foo.bar 
    end
  end
```

Why is this so?

Comment: What does assert RuntimeError do; blah(@foo); end; do?

Comment: That is a typo. And that's exactly what the error is =/ See the answer by @pablob

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `assert RuntimeError do`

+ `assert_raise RuntimeError do`